# How to avoid ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in VSCode

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code, python-requests

I'm trying to run from a tutorial in VSCode and keep getting errors about no pandas module but I know it is installed.

I've tried using "select interpreter" to swap between versions of python but then I have issues with requests module. The code below does work if I comment out the pandas module but I can't understand why this code doesn't work.

I tried using pip3 install pandas but the terminal tells me it is already installed.

[image]

The code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime
import smtplib
import csv
#import pandas as pd

def check_price():
    
    URL = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/Funny-Data-T-shirt-Mining-T-Shirt/dp/B0B68TSGCR/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=funny+data+mining&qid=1560000000&s=gateway&sr=8-1"

    html = requests.get(URL).text

    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")  
    title = soup2.find(id="productTitle").get_text().strip()
    price_whole = soup2.find(attrs= {"class": "a-price-whole"}).get_text()
    price_fraction = soup2.find(attrs= {"class": "a-price-fraction"}).get_text()
    price = (f"{price_whole.split()[0]}.{price_fraction.split()[0]}")
    today = datetime.date.today()
    header = ['Title', 'Price', 'Date']
    data = [title, price, today]
    
    
    with open("amazonscraper2.csv", "a+", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerow(data)


while(True):
    check_price()
    time.sleep(5)
    print("running")
    #df = pd.read_csv("amazonscraper2.csv")
    #print(df)
```

Comment: Maybe because you're running the script in an anaconda environment. Try deactivating it and running the script again or simply create a separate environment for each project where you can install packages separately and run scripts inside that environment.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. Confused about venv  and the like, though. Where do I go for simple guide.

Comment: For me, [this guide](https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv) works for Python venv. For Anaconda, their [user guide](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/index.html) is the best place to start.